# Relational Database Design for Customer Reviews

Tags: database, schema, relational-database

Suppose I want to create a database to store customer reviews of a restaurant.

Now suppose I have a database table called 'Qualities' of certain qualities that a restaurant has (e.g. customer service, quality of food, atmosphere, value for money etc. ) along with a more detailed description of each of these qualities.

Now let's say I also have a table called 'Reviews' of individual reviews which assign a rating to each of the aforementioned qualities in the 'Qualities' table.

This poses a dilemma: The number of columns in the 'Reviews' table is dependent on the number of rows on the 'Qualities' table. If we add a new quality to be rated in the 'Qualities' table we need to create a corresponding column in the 'Reviews' table so users can rate this quality.

What would be the best way to design a relational database for the problem above? If you include a database schema with you answer then that could be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're right in that the way you explain it, you would need a column per quality supported by the restaurant being reviewed. If the "qualities" are dynamic then it's best to make the related scoring dynamic too. So, rather than maintain the scores as columns on your review, you would be best maintaining them as rows mapping a score to each quality for a review.

I would probably go for something like this:

```
             restquality (m:n)
                |n    |n
                |1    |
user     restaurant   |
 |1       |1          |1
 |        |n       quality
 +----n-review      |1
           |1       |
           |n       |n
        reviewquality (m:n)
```

- A user may review many restaurants
- A restaurant may have many qualities and a quality can be applied to more than one restaurant (a m:n relationship managed through restquality).
- A review "reviews" a particular restaurant, giving scores per quality for the qualities pertinent to that resturant. This is managed through reviewquality that has: this review gives this score to this quality (where the parent review references the restaurant).

Important schema:

- review: reviewid(pk), userid, restid, summary
- reviewquality: reviewqualityid(pk), reviewid, qualityid, score
- restquality: restqualityid(pk), restaurantid, qualityid

Hope this helps.

Comment: A very lucid explanation - thank you very much. Good effort on the ASCII diagram too!